# Using Jquery to only animate one element whilst selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

so I'm trying to get better at using javascript and jquery, so I tried to implement a little animation. I have 2 divs in a list under each other, and my aim is, when a mouse hovers over one of the divs, it animates it's width to stretch it out, and when the mouse leaves, the div is still stretched out, only until the mouse enters another div, in which the new div will expand, and the other will return back to it's original size. I've managed to get the divs to expand and resize when entering and leaving them with the mouse, but when trying to implement a way so that only ONE div can be expanded at any time, I can never seem to get it to work.

Here's my code so far:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>         
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>       
 <style type="text/css">
 
  li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  }
  .d1, .d2, .d3, .d4{
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 210px;
  }
  
 </style>
 <script>
 
  $(document).ready(function() {     
   var state = 0;
   var selected  = 0;
   console.log(state);
   $(".d1, .d2").mouseenter(function(){
    state++;
    selected = 1;
    console.log(state);
    $(this).animate({
     width: '400px'
     });    
    });
    
   $(".d1, .d2").mouseleave(function(){
    state++;
    console.log(state);
    if (state == 2 && selected == 1) {
     $(".d1").animate({
      width: '210px'
      });
     state = 0;
     selected = 0;
     }
     });
   });
   
  </script>
  
</head>

<body>
 <div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
   <h1>Animated Hover Slide</h1></br></br>
   <ul>
    <li><div class="d1">This is some text</div></li>
    <li><div class="d2">This is some text</div></li>
 

   </ul>
    
   
  
   
  </div>
 </div>
</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also simplify a bit and just add/remove an active class to the hovered div.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("ul li").hover(function(){
      $("ul li").removeClass("active");
      $(this).addClass("active");
   });
});
```

```css
li {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
  margin:5px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

li.active {
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Animated Hover Slide</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>This is some text</li>
      <li>This is some text</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your solution, but didn't he want to learn js/jQuery (*I'm trying to get better at using javascript and jquery*). But he should definitely see this as well.

Comment: Yes, so I guess that I should just caveat that .hover() is quite literally binding handlers for mouseenter and and mouseleave events. That being said, if you know that you'll be animating and that you'll have binary states, every animation library these days is using some iteration of CSS3 animation - I think it's fair to reduce a bit.

Comment: You might simplify to just **$("ul li").removeClass("active");**.  Though rather than "ul li" I would use a class to tag where I wanted the effect

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.data()` to store state of element animation; if `selected` is `0`, animate to `400px` at `mouseenter`, set element having `className` beginning with `"d"` that is child of parent sibling to `210px`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".d1, .d2").data("selected", 0)
   .mouseenter(function() {
      if ($(this).data().selected === 0) {
        $(this).animate({
            width: '400px'
          }).data("selected", 1)
          .parent().siblings().find("[class^=d]")
          .data("selected", 0)
          .animate({
            width: '210px'
          })
      }
    })
});
```

```css
li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.d1,
.d2,
.d3,
.d4 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Animated Hover Slide</h1>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="d1">This is some text</div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="d2">This is some text</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I think I'm going to need to read up about the .data method to help understand the code more

Comment: @Sean2148 See http://api.jquery.com/data , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that answers your question: https://jsfiddle.net/d8kjLgph/

I use the `data-*` attribute to keep track of which element that is the "big one".

Edit: I changed your original code a little bit, hope that's ok!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".animate").mouseenter(function(){
    /*
   Checking that the .animate-element the mouse enters is a "small" one
    */
    if($(this).attr("data-active") != "true"){
      $(".animate").attr("data-active", "false"); // Reseting all divs to "small"
      $(this).attr("data-active", "true"); // Keep track of which one that's active (the big one)

      $(".animate:not([data-active='true']").animate({ // Animate all that's not active to "small"
        width: '210px'
      }, 500);

      $(this).animate({ // Animate the active one to "big"
        width: '400px'
      }, 500);

    }
  });
});
```

```css
li {
  padding-top: 30px;
  font-size: 20pt;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}

.animate{
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 210px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fluid-container">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <h1>Animated Hover Slide</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><div class="animate">This is some text</div></li>
      <li><div class="animate">This is some text</div></li>
      <li><div class="animate">This is some text</div></li>
      <li><div class="animate">This is some text</div></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's a bit easier for me to understand than guest271314's code, but a lot of this code is new to me so I'll need to read up to understand it more, thanks again though!